# Error loading css, cannot find "theme".css resource of "primefaces-bluesky-1.0.10" library

Tags: primefaces, themes

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.0 and javax.faces-2.2.8.jar in my project. I'm facing a problem in applying a theme. I added the blue-sky.1.0.10.jar to the project (drag&drop lib to WebContent/WEB-INF/lib) and configured in web.xml as following.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>blue-sky.1.0.10</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When I run the project, I obtain this exception

javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading css, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-bluesky-1.0.10" library

I downloaded theme  from
http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/

ProjectFacets Config:
Dynamic Web Module 3.0
Java 1.7
JavaScript 1.0
JavaServer Faces 2.2

How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your skin name is wrong

```
<param-value>blue-sky.1.0.10</param-value>
```

try

```
<param-value>blueSky</param-value>

<param-value>bluesky</param-value>
```

or blue-sky :)